# How to fix Centos lxc containers when random commands are hanging?

Tags: linux, centos, containers, freeze, lxc

The host server is Centos 7.0.1406. I am creating lxc Centos 7.2.1511 containers using the following command:

```
lxc-create -n test-container -t /etc/lxc/templates/lxc-centos --lxcpath=/var/lib/lxc/
```

The lxc container is created and I can start it and attach to it like this:

```
lxc-create -n test-container -t /etc/lxc/templates/lxc-centos --lxcpath=/var/lib/lxc/ 

lxc-start -d -n test-container

lxc-attach -n test-container
```

Once I am inside `test-container`, I try to run random commands, such as `adduser foo` or `yum install emacs` and they will always hang like this:

> $ adduser foobar
>
> ...

or like this:

> Is this ok [y/N]: y   Running transaction check   Running transaction
>   test   Transaction test succeeded   Running transaction     Installing
>   : freetype-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64
>   1/132    Installing : libICE-1.0.9-2.el7.x86_64
>   2/132    Installing : 2:libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64
>   3/132    Installing : libSM-1.2.2-2.el7.x86_64
>   4/132    Installing : libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64
>   5/132    Installing : atk-2.14.0-1.el7.x86_64
>   6/132    Installing : jasper-libs-1.900.1-29.el7.x86_64
>   7/132    Installing : 1:emacs-filesystem-24.3-18.el7.noarch
>   8/132    Installing : libthai-0.1.14-9.el7.x86_64
>   9/132    Installing : mesa-libglapi-10.6.5-3.20150824.el7.x86_64
>   10/132
>
> ...

At first, I thought it was a package problem, but even commands like `adduser` are hanging. I tried rebooting the container, creating the containers using salt lxc module, updating the kernel on the host, avoiding updating packages, cloning the container, and many others...

I ran out of ideas, I am about to switch to Debian containers, but I would like to know if anybody has encountered a similar problem before and knows how to fix it.

Comment: i am working with diego on this:  The hanging starts on seemingly random events. sometimes right after booting the container, sometimes a while later.

After we rebooted the host, some older containers were still running fine, only recently created or updated ones seem to be affected from the problem.

In one container, we were able to trigger the problem by upgrading the chkconfig package. However that was not the cause of the problem because after the reboot, even a container which had the older version of chkconfig now has the problem. it was running fine until before the reboot.

Comment: it appears that if we start a container with libvirt tools instead of lxc tools, the problem does not appear. unfortunately lxc-tools are a lot easier to use: `lxc-create -n container-name -t centos; lxc-start -n container-name` vs manually creating a container file tree and then activating it with: `virt-install --connect lxc:/// --name container-name --ram 512 --vcpu 1 --filesystem /var/lib/lxc/container-name/rootfs/,/` and later `virsh --connect lxc:/// start container-name` (and the libvirt version does not even set the container hostname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this appears to be a bug with the version of the lxc tools currently in centos: `lxc-1.0.8-1.el7.x86_64`.

using different tools, such as libvirt, or upgrading lxc to the latest current version 1.1.5 solves the problem.

Comment: this issue is not being discussed anywhere else to my knowledge, and diego had to stop working on the project before he had time to write up a bugreport.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Version 1.0.10-2.el7 has some bug.